# Delaying prgram to keep text on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay

I'm making a min text adventure and want to have some text displayed for a few seconds before moving on with the program. I found stuff like await etc but can't seem te implement them in my code.

Here's my code:

```
void state_pad_1 (){
    text.text = "You put the " + weight + "kg on pad 1.\n\n ";
    if (weight ==weight1){      
        myState = States.room_2;}
    else {
    myState = States.room_1;    
    }   
}
```

So the delay should be between the text and the if statement.

Comment: Don't know if it will work in Unity but an easy wait in C# is `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`. The 1000 is milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easily done with [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)
For example you should convert your method into something like this:

```
IEnumerator state_pad_1 ()
{
  text.text = "You put the " + weight + "kg on pad 1.\n\n ";
  //enter number of seconds you want instead of 5
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); 
  if (weight ==weight1){      
      myState = States.room_2;}
  else {
  myState = States.room_1;    
  }   
}
```

But keep in mind that coroutines are called in a different way, for example:

```
StartCoroutine("WaitAndPrint");
```

If you try to use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` it will kinda [freeze your app](https://answers.unity.com/questions/379440/a-simple-wait-function-without-coroutine-c.html), so coroutines are better solution.